# Foursquare API - Venues section doesn't work

Tags: api, foursquare

I have a problem with Foursquare API.
I'm trying to filter by section (food, cofee, ...), but I still have answer with everything and not only for the section.

My request :
`https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/search?client_id=MYID&client_secret=MYSECRET&near="+city+"&section=food&m=foursquare`

Do you have any idea ?

Thanks all

Romain